# Get uniq nested object array with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

My data had nested objects with array. I want to make the nested object atrribute unique from the output. Currenly I'm using lodash v4 above, I found a solution suitable but only works in lodash v3.

**Data**

```
[{
   menu: { id: 1 },
   other: { data: "another1" }
},
{
   menu: { id: 2 },
   other: { data: "another2" }
},
{
   menu: { id: 1 },
   other: { data: "another1" }
}]
```

**Expected output**

```
[{
   menu: { id: 1 },
   other: { data: "another1" }
},
{
   menu: { id: 2 },
   other: { data: "another2" }
}]
```

Similar lodash v3 solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31113865). What is the solution for v4? Solution without lodash still accepted as long as the codes are running faster and simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#uniq) method as below.

```js
var arr = [{
  menu: {
    id: 1
  }
}, {
  menu: {
    id: 2
  }
}, {
  menu: {
    id: 1
  }
}];

var unique = _.uniq(arr, 'menu.id');
console.log(unique);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

With lodash 4.x.x, use [`uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy)

```js
var arr = [{
  menu: {
    id: 1
  },
  other: {
    data: "another1"
  }
}, {
  menu: {
    id: 2
  },
  other: {
    data: "another2"
  }
}, {
  menu: {
    id: 1
  },
  other: {
    data: "another1"
  }
}];

console.log(_.uniqBy(arr, 'menu.id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `lodash` .using [`Array#reduce`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjQi8qznvnTAhXJgI8KHRqaANQQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce&usg=AFQjCNG5y6qS8juF9mnkgIEZQgeRUeoJ3A&sig2=JrgRXL6c7I5csr0DJR_qDA)

```js
var a =[{
   menu: { id: 1 },
   other: { data: "another1" }
},
{
   menu: { id: 2 },
   other: { data: "another2" }
},
{
   menu: { id: 1 },
   other: { data: "another1" }
}]

var res =[];
 var fin =a.reduce((a,b)=> {
if(!res.includes(b.menu.id)){
res.push(b.menu.id)
a.push(b)
}
return a;
},[])
console.log(fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
_.uniqBy(yourarray, e=>e.menu.id)
```

```js
var data = [{
   menu: { id: 1 },
   other: { data: "another1" }
},
{
   menu: { id: 2 },
   other: { data: "another2" }
},
{
   menu: { id: 1 },
   other: { data: "another1" }
}]

console.log(_.uniqBy(data, e=>e.menu.id));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```